# High chi-square of the intercept in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, intercept

I run logistic regression models where the event rate is generally very low. In my models I get a large intercept term. What bothers me is the exceptionally high chi-square of the intercept term. How do I interpret this condition?

Answer (score 1):

The intercept term is the parameter estimate when all the independent variables are 0.  One way that you could get the results you describe is if 0 is not a meaningful value for the IVs.  E.g. suppose one of your IVs is annual income in $. Then a 0 value is far outside the data.

Comment: I like year of birth as an example

Comment: What about the high chi-square? Does it indicate that the intercept has an exceptional contribution in the model? And the independent variables poorly explain the target?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything.